# $statement execute and returns true but doesn't affect any rows in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the insert statement in my code for add operation runs perfectly and also inserts values in my table but 
the update statement does not run properly.
the error code and error info I get is: 00000 Error occurred:00000::
I also tried adding my :GroupName and all the others inside single quotes but still the same issue.
this is my code for insert:

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    include('function.php');
    if(isset($_POST["operation"]))
    {
        if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
        {
            $Diwaliinvites = false;
            $SubscribedToMailingList = false;
            if(isset($_POST['Diwaliinvites']))
            {
                $Diwaliinvites = true;

            }
            else
            {
                $Diwaliinvites = false;

            }
            if(isset($_POST['SubscribedToMailingList']))
            {
                $SubscribedToMailingList = true;

            }
            else
            {
                $SubscribedToMailingList = false;

            }
            $Datetimestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $statement = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO tab_organizers (GroupName, ContactName, Address1, Address2, City, 
            Province, PostalCode, Country, Title, Telephone1, Telephone2, FaxNumber, SchoolGeneralEmail, Email, 
            SubscribedToMailingList, HowDidYouHear, Comments, Datetimestamp, Diwaliinvites)
            VALUES 
            (:GroupName, :ContactName, :Address1, :Address2, :City, :Province, :PostalCode, 
            :Country, :Title, :Telephone1, :Telephone2, :FaxNumber, :SchoolGeneralEmail, :Email, 
            :SubscribedToMailingList, :HowDidYouHear, :Comments, :Datetimestamp, :Diwaliinvites)
            ");

            $result = $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':GroupName' => $_POST["GroupName"],
                    ':ContactName' => $_POST["ContactName"],
                    ':Address1' => $_POST["Address1"],
                    ':Address2' => $_POST["Address2"],
                    ':City' => $_POST["City"],
                    ':Province' => $_POST["Province"],
                    ':PostalCode' => $_POST["PostalCode"],
                    ':Country' => $_POST["Country"],
                    ':Title' => $_POST["Title"],
                    ':Telephone1' => $_POST["Telephone1"],
                    ':Telephone2' => $_POST["Telephone2"],
                    ':FaxNumber' => $_POST["FaxNumber"],
                    ':SchoolGeneralEmail' => $_POST["SchoolGeneralEmail"],
                    ':Email' => $_POST["Email"],
                    ':SubscribedToMailingList' => $SubscribedToMailingList,
                    ':HowDidYouHear' => $_POST["HowDidYouHear"],
                    ':Comments' => $_POST["Comments"],
                    ':Datetimestamp'  => $Datetimestamp,
                    ':Diwaliinvites' => $Diwaliinvites
                )
            );

            if(!empty($result))
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Data Not Inserted';
            }
        }
        if($_POST["operation"] == "Edit")
        {   
            $Datetimestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $Diwaliinvites = false;
            $SubscribedToMailingList = false;
            if(isset($_POST['Diwaliinvites']))
            {
                $Diwaliinvites = true;
                // echo $Diwaliinvites;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['SubscribedToMailingList']))
            {
                $SubscribedToMailingList = true;
                // echo $SubscribedToMailingList;
            }
            try {
                $statement = $connection->prepare(
                    "
                    UPDATE tab_organizers SET 
                    GroupName= :GroupName ,
                    ContactName= :ContactName,
                    Address1= :Address1,
                    Address2= :Address2,
                    City= :City,
                    Province= :Province,
                    PostalCode= :PostalCode,
                    Country= :Country,
                    Title= :Title,
                    Telephone1= :Telephone1,
                    Telephone2= :Telephone2,
                    FaxNumber= :FaxNumber,
                    SchoolGeneralEmail= :SchoolGeneralEmail,
                    Email= :Email,
                    SubscribedToMailingList= :SubscribedToMailingList,
                    HowDidYouHear= :HowDidYouHear,
                    Comments= :Comments,
                    Datetimestamp= :Datetimestamp,
                    Diwaliinvites= :Diwaliinvites 
                    WHERE OrganizerID = :OrganizerID;
                    ");
                    $statement -> bindparam(':GroupName', $_POST["GroupName"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':ContactName', $_POST["ContactName"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Address1', $_POST["Address1"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Address2', $_POST["Address2"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':City', $_POST["City"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Province', $_POST["Province"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':PostalCode', $_POST["PostalCode"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Country', $_POST["Country"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Title', $_POST["Title"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Telephone1', $_POST["Telephone1"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Telephone2', $_POST["Telephone2"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':FaxNumber', $_POST["FaxNumber"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':SchoolGeneralEmail', $_POST["SchoolGeneralEmail"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Email', $_POST["Email"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':HowDidYouHear', $_POST["HowDidYouHear"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Comments', $_POST["Comments"]);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Datetimestamp', $Datetimestamp);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':SubscribedToMailingList', $SubscribedToMailingList);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':Diwaliinvites', $Diwaliinvites);
                    $statement -> bindparam(':OrganizerID', $_POST["OrganizerID"]);

                    $result = $statement->execute();
                    // array(
                    //     ':GroupName' => $_POST["GroupName"],
                    //     ':ContactName' => $_POST["ContactName"],
                    //     ':Address1' => $_POST["Address1"],
                    //     ':Address2' => $_POST["Address2"],
                    //     ':City' => $_POST["City"],
                    //     ':Province' => $_POST["Province"],
                    //     ':PostalCode' => $_POST["PostalCode"],
                    //     ':Country' => $_POST["Country"],
                    //     ':Title' => $_POST["Title"],
                    //     ':Telephone1' => $_POST["Telephone1"],
                    //     ':Telephone2' => $_POST["Telephone2"],
                    //     ':FaxNumber' => $_POST["FaxNumber"],
                    //     ':SchoolGeneralEmail' => $_POST["SchoolGeneralEmail"],
                    //     ':Email' => $_POST["Email"],
                    //     ':SubscribedToMailingList' => $SubscribedToMailingList,
                    //     ':HowDidYouHear' => $_POST["HowDidYouHear"],
                    //     ':Comments' => $_POST["Comments"],
                    //     ':Datetimestamp'  => $Datetimestamp,
                    //     ':Diwaliinvites' => $Diwaliinvites,
                    //     ':OrganizerID' => $_POST["OrganizerID"]
                    // )
                // );
                $statement->closeCursor();

                $number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();
                $done = $statement !== false ? true : false;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                console.log($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), array('exception' => $e));
            }

            if($result === false)
            {
                echo 'Data Not Updated';
                echo $number_filter_row;
                echo $done;
                echo $statement->errorCode();
                // echo PDO::errorInfo();
                echo 'Error occurred:'.implode(":",$connection->errorInfo());
            }
            else{
                echo 'Data Updated';
                echo $number_filter_row;
                echo $done;
                echo $statement->errorCode();
                // echo PDO::errorInfo();
                echo 'Error occurred:'.implode(":",$connection->errorInfo());
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

EDIT 1:
this is my code for edit button ajax function in js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){
        var OrganizerID = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(OrganizerID);
        $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"post",  
            data:{OrganizerID:OrganizerID},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){  
                // alert(data);
                // $('input[name="Diwaliinvites"][value="'+ID+'"]').prop('checked',true);
                $('#Datetimestamp').val(data.Datetimestamp);
                $('#GroupName').val(data.GroupName);
                $('#ContactName').val(data.ContactName);
                $('#Address1').val(data.Address1);
                $('#Address2').val(data.Address2);
                $('#City').val(data.City);
                $('#Province').val(data.Province);
                $('#PostalCode').val(data.PostalCode);
                $('#Country').val(data.Country);
                $('#Title').val(data.Title);
                $('#Telephone1').val(data.Telephone1);
                $('#Telephone2').val(data.Telephone2);
                $('#FaxNumber').val(data.FaxNumber);
                $('#SchoolGeneralEmail').val(data.SchoolGeneralEmail);
                $('#Email').val(data.Email);
                $('#HowDidYouHear').val(data.HowDidYouHear);
                $('#Comments').val(data.Comments);
                $('#Diwaliinvites').val(data.Diwaliinvites);
                $('#SubscribedToMailingList').val(data.SubscribedToMailingList);
                $('#visitoraddmodal').modal("show"); 
                $('.modal-title').text("Edit User");
                $('#OrganizerID').val(OrganizerID);
                $('#action').val("Edit");
                $('#operation').val("Edit"); 
            }  
        });
    });
```

the OrganizerID I get is 1064.

Comment: Have you check what `$_POST["OrganizerID"]` contains and that this matches the row in the database?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it right now, it says 1 when it should say 1064. I'm doing this for the first time so I don't know much, can you please tell how to fix that...

Comment: You will have to check the HTML that is calling this page as it sounds like the 1 is coming from there.

Comment: this is my code for the edit data button ajax function, can you check my edit 1 please.

Comment: my OrganizerID in my script in 1064 which is correct, but when I console.log(data) for my ajax function, the OrganizerID is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was because I was trying to include my delete_modal.php file in my index file. I don't know how they are related but that solved my problem.